# How can I keep my sinusoid in phase with its input after filtering?

Tags: filter, frequency, low-pass

A section of a circuit I'm working with makes a sinusoid from a square wave by passing it through an 8th order filter ([MAX293](http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/analog/analog-filters/MAX293.html)). Up until now, everything was ok, but I was told recently that the input (square wave) and output (sinusoid) have to be in phase. Because of the LPF, it adds a phase shift and because the input frequency is variable (0-5khz), the phase shift is also variable.

How can I keep them in phase for the entire frequency region they operate at ? What should  I be looking at ?

Comment: Just to be sure, you are talking of a single pure tone, am I right? That's not trivial anyway, I think you will need a PLL.

Comment: Ya it would just be a single frequency. Wouldn't a PLL give me a square wave ? As soon as I filter it, the phase is off. I would imagine, that my compensation would have to happen after the filtering and use some sort comparison with the reference signal - perhaps look at their zero crossing and stop the sine wave until it matches the zero crossing.. :S

Comment: Are you saying that your circuit NEEDS to have input and output in phase OR are you saying that someone told you the filter won't work if they are not in-phase?

Comment: The circuit NEEDS to have input and output in phase. The circuit is not suitable for its purpose if they are in not.

Comment: My idea is that your pll uses as input the square wave and as "error" input the sin wave. I am assuming that it uses zero crossing or something similar.

Comment: Its an idea. Never used a PLL before, but I'll look into now and see if I can do something with it. Do PLL work with low frequency ? Max frequency would be about 5Khz.

Comment: Yeah I think so... Why not anyway? Maybe there's a better way, you can equalize the phase with another filter after the MAX, but if you have strict phase specs I'm afraid closed loop control is mandatory, and PLL is the way to go.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/logic/phase-locked-loop-pll-oscillator-products.page)

Comment: I think you may be right with the PLL. I stumbled upon the following link, and it looks like something I'm trying to achieve. http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/4504

Comment: 1. How much phase jitter can you stand between the square wave and the sine wave?  2. How much harmonic content can you stand in the sine wave? 3. What is the lowest frequency sine wave you need to generate?  4. How much amplitude variation can you stand in the sine wave over its frequency range?  5. When the square wave changes frequency, how much time can you stand before the sine wave catches up? 6. What will be the greatest rate of change of frequency of the square wave?

Comment: 3. ~0Hz. Right now I have about 0.1Hz. 4. Prefereably, little to none. I might be able to compensate for any variation with another part of the circuit that controls amplitude. The remainder of the questions I cannot answer properly. I'm interfacing to a black box and I don't have any other information other than - I have to try and see what happens.Obviously the best answer would be, as small as possible but not sure how much complexity that will add.

Comment: @efox29: Is it possible for you to generate the square wave or is it something coming out of the black box over which you have no control?

Answer (score 2):

You have two options apart from the PLL (which may or may not meet your requirements : there will inevitably be delays between input and output if the frequency changes, while the PLL settles to the new frequency. Given the comments, a PLL capable of tracking down to 0.1Hz will be quite a beast to get right)

1) Delay the input signal in the same manner that the filter delays the output.

This is easier if the filter is a linear phase filter such as a Bessel, or you can use digital filters such as an FIR filter, and a matching digital delay.

It's not impossible otherwise : you can design an "all pass network" aka "group delay equaliser" with the same delay characteristics (phase response) as the filter : however after this, the square wave will generally no longer be a square wave. Whether that matters or not I can't say, I don't know the application.

Given a linear phase filter, the group delay equaliser should be relatively simple and preserve the square wave.

2) Generate one waveform from the other without filtering.

It is possible to generate a triangle waveform from a square by integration (this generates a 90 degree phase shift so you may need to generate two square waves in quadrature). From the triangle, you can use a non-linear network (resistors and diodes, as a "soft clipper) to approximate a sine wave. Better that 2% harmonic content is possible : see the "ICL8038" for an old example of this technique. This only works well if the square wave amplitude is constant.

But it's much simpler to generate a square from a sine, if your application permits...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a symmetric filter the phase should not change. However, for non-symmetric filters (e.g., Butterworth) you need to run the filter twice to recover the phase. Once on the original data (this would change the phase), then on the filtered data but in reverse order (this changes the phase back to the original), i.e.:

1. filtered_data(1:N)=Filter(data(1:N))
2. samePhase_filtered_data=Filter(filtered_data(N:1))
3. samePhase_filtered_data_rightOrder=samePhase_filtered_data(N:1)